# efficient way of generating semi-random sequences

Tags: algorithm

Quite often, I have to generate sequences of numbers in some semi-random way, which means that it is not totally random, but has to have some other property. For example we need a random sequence of 1,2,3 and 4s, but no number must be repeated three times in a row. These are usually not very complicated to do, but I ran into a tricky one: I need to generate a semi-random sequence that is a bit over 400 long, is composed of 1,2,3 and 4s, each number must appear the same amount of times (or if the sum is not divisible by four than as close as you can get it) and they must not repeat 3 times in a row (so 1,3,4,4,4,2 is not ok ).

I tried to methods:

1. Create a list which has the desired length and number of numbers; shuffle; check if ok for consecutive numbers if not, shuffle again.
2. Create a list which has the desired length and number of numbers; generate all permutations and select which are ok; save these for later and randomly select one of them when needed.

Method number one runs for minutes before yielding any sequence that is ok and method number two generates so many permutations my jupter notebook gave up.

Here's the python code for the first one

```
from random import shuffle

v = []
for x in range(108):
    v += [1,2,3,4]
shouldicontinue = 1
while shouldicontinue:
    shuffle(v)
    shouldicontinue = 0
    for h in range(len(v)-1):
        if v[h] == v[h+1] and v[h] == v[h+2]:

            shouldicontinue = 1
            break
        else:
            pass
```

and the second one

```
from random import shuffle
import itertools
v = []
for x in range(108):
    v += [1,2,3,4]
good = []
for l in itertools.permutations(v):
    notok = 0
    for h in range(len(v)-1):
        if v[h] == v[h+1] and v[h] == v[h+2]:

            notok = 1
            break
        else:
            pass
    if not notok:
        good.append(v)
```

I'm looking for a way to solve this problem in an efficient way, i.e.: if it runs in real time, it doesn't need more than say a minute to generate on slower computers or if it is prepared in advance in someway (like the idea of method 2), it can be prepared on some moderate level computer in a few hours.

Comment: Do you need uniformity over the space of all possible such sequences?

Comment: @DSM In a practical sense, probably, not, but I'm also interested in this academically, so in that sense, yes, uniformity would be the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can check all the permutations of a `>400` length list, the universe will likely have died. Thus you need another approach.

Here, I recommend trying to insert the elements in the list at random, but shifting to the next index when the insertion would break one of the requirements.

Cycling through your elements, *1* to *4* in your case, should ensure an insertion is always possible.

```py
from itertools import cycle, islice
from random import randint

def has_repeated(target, n, lst):
    """A helper to check if insertion would break the max repetition requirement"""
    count = 0
    for el in lst:
        count += el == target
        if count == n:
            return True
    return False

def sequence(length, max_repeat, elements=(1, 2, 3, 4)):
    # Iterator that will yield our elements in cycle
    values = islice(cycle(elements), length)

    seq = []
    for value in values:
        # Pick an insertion index at random
        init_index = randint(0, len(seq))

        # Loop over indices from that index until a legal position is found
        for shift in range(len(seq) + 1):
            index = init_index - shift
            slice_around_index = seq[max(0, index - max_repeat):index + max_repeat]

            # If the insertion would cause no forbidden subsequence, insert
            if not has_repeated(value, max_repeat, slice_around_index):
                seq.insert(index, value)
                break

        # This will likely never happen, except if a solution truly does not exist
        else:
            raise ValueError('failed to generate the sequence')
    return seq
```

### Sample

Here is some sample output to check the result is correct.

```
for _ in range(10):
    print(sequence(25, 2))
```

#### Output

```
[4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3]
[4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4]
[4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3]
```

Efficiency-wise, it takes around 10ms to generate a list of length 10,000 with he same requirements. Hinting that this might be an efficient enough solution for most purpose.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work very well, after a quick check! I will look at it a bit more closely probably, tomorrow, so I'm sure I understand what you are doing.

Comment: @fbence dont hesitate to tag me and ask question if you need

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be possible (with about 4 gigabytes of memory and 1 minute of precomputation) to generate uniformly distributed random sequences faster than 1 second per random sequence.

The idea is to prepare a cache of results for the question "How many sequences with exactly a 1s, b 2s, c 3s, d 4s are there which end with count copies of a particular digit?".

Once you have this cache, then you can compute how many sequences (N) there are that satisfy your constraint, and can generate one at random by picking a random number n between 1 and N and using the cache to generate the n^th sequence.

To save memory in the cache you can use a couple of tricks:

1. The answer is symmetric in a/b/c/d so you only need to store results with a>=b>=c>=d
2. The count of the last digit will always be 1 or 2 in legal sequences

These tricks should mean the cache only needs to hold about 40 million results.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
rc = random.choices([1,2,3,4])
for _ in range(22):
  if rc[-1] == 1:
    rc = rc + random.choices([2,3,4])
    rc = rc + random.choices([1,2,3,4])
  if rc[-1] == 2:
    rc = rc + random.choices([1,3,4])
    rc = rc + random.choices([1,2,3,4])
  if rc[-1] == 3:
    rc = rc + random.choices([2,1,4])
    rc = rc + random.choices([1,2,3,4])
  if rc[-1] == 4:
    rc = rc + random.choices([2,3,1])
    rc = rc + random.choices([1,2,3,4])
print(rc)
```

Comment: it will be 'double' randomly, it will never be 'triple'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).